# Raphael.js fill img position and size

Tags: svg, raphael

I found here that you can use an image to fill a rectangle, but can you set the position or size of the image dynamically?  I was hoping to find a fill-position type attribute. Anybody know if this exists?

Comment: Is the problem to take it rectangle as viewbox and use img as background?

Comment: Please show us some code you are using now to make it easier to help you